# How to determine the class from which a specified method originated?

Tags: ruby

I got this question from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466048/array-find-method-problem). A method call like `object.m` does not always mean the class of "object" has a "m" method, just like the find method to a Array object is not directly originated from Array object, but from the mixed-in Enumerable module. My question is, given a method, how can we determine the class from which the method originated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any class/object method is an object in Ruby, and has some methods of it's own.

So you can do this:

```
[].method(:count).inspect
=> "#<Method: Array#count>"

[].method(:detect).inspect
=> "#<Method: Array(Enumerable)#detect>"
```

Quick bit of RegEx and you're done.

Answer (score 7):

tobyhede's answer is awesome, but I just did a bit of digging in `irb` and there's no need to slice up the output of `#inspect`. The `Method` class

```
>> Object.new.method(:inspect)
=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#inspect>
```

has some useful methods of its own:

```
>> Object.new.method(:inspect).methods - Object.methods
=> ["owner", "call", "to_proc", "unbind", "arity", "receiver", "[]"]
```

In particular the `#owner` method, which returns the owner as a proper object:

```
>> [].method(:count).owner
=> Array
>> [].method(:detect).owner
=> Enumerable
```

Comment: awesome find, this will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you use caller() to give you the backtrace see:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005955

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking something like this could work

```
def print_ancestor_definitions(cl,method)
  ancestors = cl.ancestors
  p ancestors.join(' < ') #Print heirarchy
  p "Searching..."
  ancestors.each do |c|
    if c.instance_methods.include? method
      p "#{c} defines #{method} as an instance method!"
    elsif c.singleton_methods.include? method
      p "#{c} defines #{method} as a singleton method"
    else
      p "#{c} doesn't define #{method}"
    end
  end
end

print_ancestor_definitions(Array,'find')
# >> "Array < Enumerable < Object < Kernel"
# >> "Searching..."
# >> "Array defines find as an instance method!"
# >> "Enumerable defines find as an instance method!"
# >> "Object doesn't define find"
# >> "Kernel doesn't define find"
```

I suppose the last one to have the method is the one who defines it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure we can precisely find where a method come from, when you include a mixin, all the methods become part of your class as if you did put them there. See answer from dylanfm for an approx.

Comment: method.inspect will tell you if a method is attached to a Mixin